# Android Binder native service called from Java

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-binder

I've created a native binder service with a few transactions types.

At the moment i have native proxy ( Bp ) for clients, but i want to give Java clients the possibility to use my service.

Basically, the Bp should be Java i think. I've found some stuff about JNI, but incomplete. I need to use JNI inside Bn?

Also, a callback mechanism ( sporadic event from service to a specific client method ) should be available. I've done it in native.

Comment: I've managed to perform a simple call using the example from here https://github.com/cloudchou/NativeBinderJavaClientDemo/blob/master/FClient/src/com/cloud/test/CloudManagerProxy.java Callbacks from native to JNI and transfering of complex data structures remain as an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my first answer ever...

As mentioned by Cumatru I also used https://github.com/cloudchou/NativeBinderJavaClientDemo.

I have not yet fully understood the whole process, but at least it works and it's a way to move forward with a pretty "simple" example. I am on a very basic android level, so please bear with me and help improve the answer in whatever way you'd like.

There seem to be three parts:
1. A server process made in c++ running natively.
2. An android application client.
3. A simple java-client that will be built into a .jar-file.

No alteration to the code seems to be necessary, at least for the simple java-client and the c++-server.

- Build and push the server-application to your target. Run it in an adb shell.
- Build and push the java-client (.jar-file), called fclient, to your target in /system/framework/
- Run the java-client using the fclient-script
- An addition will be made on the two integers sent from the client, and replied back to the server.

Hopefully it works for you too.